# Querying using returned values in Meteor with Iron Router

Tags: meteor, iron-router

In my Meteor app I have **Lists** which have **Items**. The **Items** can belong to multiple **Lists**, so the **Lists** contain a field with an array of **Item** IDs. When I go to a single **List** view I want a data object with the **Items** queried from this array of IDs. I think the query would look like this:

```
Items.find({ _id: { $in:  theArrayOfIds } });
```

However how/where do I make this query when I load my single **List** view? At the moment this is my route declaration:

```
this.route('list', {
  path: '/list/:_id',
  data: function() {
    return {
        list: Lists.findOne(this.params._id)
     }
  }
});
```

Can I point at the future result of the list object somehow? Or do I make this query somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Iron Router, the data value of your route can be an object as well as a function. See [here in the documentation](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/dev/DOCS.md#data). Therefore you can return both the items and the list in the data call as follows:

```
this.route('list', {
  path: '/list/:_id',
  data: {
    list: function(){
      var id = Router._currentController.params._id;
      return Lists.findOne(id);
    },
    items: function(){
      var id = Router._currentController.params._id;
      var list = Lists.findOne(id);
      if (!!list){
        /* assuming your array of item ids is a field on list named items */
        var theArrayOfIds = list.items;
      }
      return !!list && Items.find({ _id: {$in: theArrayOfIds}});
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this. However I found when I tried to implement your solution that if you don't return data as a function you cannot access this.params._id. However I found that returning a function with these 2 functions inside successfully did what I wanted. If you edit your answer for that [or tell me I'm wrong] I can mark it as accepted.

Comment: Hi iiz. You are correct, this.params._id will not access the path id inside the data object. After a bit of digging I found that using Router._currentController.params._id instead of this.params._id with a data object will do the trick, and edited my answer above. You should now be able to return a function per your solution, or alternatively, the data object containing 'list' and 'items' per my example.